# How does this Precision, High-Speed Transimpedance Amplifier work?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, transimpedance, transimpedance-amplifier

I am confused by the equivalent circuit of the [OPA380](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa380.pdf?ts=1710051264930&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.bg%252F), a precision Transimpedance Amplifier from Texas Instruments. The internals of the amplifier are pictured below:

[image]

I assume the integrator and the RC filter at its output are there in some filtering capacity, perhaps to remove any DC offset?

I would think the second op-amp with its RC components would act as an integrator, or some kind of low-pass filter, and attenuate only high frequencies, thereby leaving the dc offset/component of the signal intact. So, why have it there in the first place?

**How does the op-amp integrator enhance the performance of the whole circuit?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the right hunch.

The upper amplifier is a fast but not very DC-accurate amplifier. The bottom amplifier is a classic DC servo integrator with negative gain. It nulls out the DC offset of the top amplifier.

> How does it null the offset?

DC on pin 2 is measured relative to pin 3, integrated inverted, and fed to (top:+). Any long-term DC offset on pin 2 will be thus compensated by appropriately driving (top:+) so that pin 2 is at the same potential as pin 3. The compensation path of course goes through pin 6, external Rf, and back to pin 2. That's how the voltage on pin 2 can be controlled.

The idea is that the photodiode is connected to a virtual ground, and the current into that virtual ground is measured by driving the opposite current from pin 6 into Rf.

> Doesn't it also remove some current from the already tiny photodiode current?

The 1MΩ resistor at DC is open circuit since it connects to the high-impedance input of lower op-amp, which is also open-circuit at DC. At AC, 1MOhm is between two virtual grounds, so it won't do much either. Recall that the voltage at pin 2 of the chip is same as on pin 3, and typically is ground.

Comment: I haven't seen this type of DC servo before? How does it null the offset? Doesn't it also remove some current from the already tiny photodiode current?

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs Let me know if the edits to the answer are sufficient.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs It does remove some current. But only at startup to stabilize the integrator to the DC operating point governed by the op-amp offset voltages. And because the integrator is so slow, it has a negligible effect at AC.

Comment: So I did a wee bit of simulation of the circuit in the OPA380's datasheet in LTspice with an OPA316 and came to the following conclusions: The secondary op-amp integrates the combined ac and dc components at the inverting terminal of the main amplifier, averages the AC components to zero and only passes the, now inverted, DC to the non-inverting input. The circuit will not get rid of any DC component of the input current signal.

Comment: I don't think I could apply anything gleaned from the OPA380's internals to usual, discrete op-amps in the context of transimpedance amplifiers, seems a bit too much for regular applications.

Comment: @Virgil_Tibbs I have put several circuits just like it together over the years. They work great, and with discrete parts you can do a much better job of selecting for speed and accuracy separately. OPA380 is presumably a single-die device so both op amps need to come from the same process. That forces compromises. If 380 were a two-die device, that would be like having two discrete parts integrated on a common lead frame. Such parts exist - usually for special applications and expensive.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! Thank you for your explanations, much appreciated!